# Issue with struct assign values in C using ESP-IDF

Tags: c, struct, esp32, esp-idf

I have 2 code setup wifi station for ESP32 using ESP-IDF:

Code A using initialize struct

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
    .sta = {
        .ssid = "my_ssid",
        .password = "my_ssid_password"
    }
};

ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config));
```

Code B using assign value to struct

```
static uint8_t wifi_ssid[32] = "my_ssid";
static uint8_t wifi_pwd[64] = "my_ssid_password";

...

wifi_config_t wifi_config;
memset(wifi_config.sta.ssid, 0, 32);
memcpy(wifi_config.sta.ssid, wifi_ssid, 32);

memset(wifi_config.sta.password, 0, 64);
memcpy(wifi_config.sta.password, wifi_pwd, 64);
....
```

And wifi_config_t struct look like this:

```
typedef union {
    wifi_ap_config_t  ap;  /**< configuration of AP */
    wifi_sta_config_t sta; /**< configuration of STA */
} wifi_config_t;


/** @brief STA configuration settings for the ESP32 */
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ssid[32];      /**< SSID of target AP. */
    uint8_t password[64];  /**< Password of target AP. */
    wifi_scan_method_t scan_method;    /**< do all channel scan or fast scan */
    bool bssid_set;        /**< whether set MAC address of target AP or not. Generally, station_config.bssid_set needs to be 0; and it needs to be 1 only when users need to check the MAC address of the AP.*/
    uint8_t bssid[6];     /**< MAC address of target AP*/
    uint8_t channel;       /**< channel of target AP. Set to 1~13 to scan starting from the specified channel before connecting to AP. If the channel of AP is unknown, set it to 0.*/
    uint16_t listen_interval;   /**< Listen interval for ESP32 station to receive beacon when WIFI_PS_MAX_MODEM is set. Units: AP beacon intervals. Defaults to 3 if set to 0. */
    wifi_sort_method_t sort_method;    /**< sort the connect AP in the list by rssi or security mode */
    wifi_scan_threshold_t  threshold;     /**< When sort_method is set, only APs which have an auth mode that is more secure than the selected auth mode and a signal stronger than the minimum RSSI will be used. */
    wifi_pmf_config_t pmf_cfg;    /**< Configuration for Protected Management Frame. Will be advertized in RSN Capabilities in RSN IE. */
    uint32_t rm_enabled:1;        /**< Whether Radio Measurements are enabled for the connection */
    uint32_t btm_enabled:1;       /**< Whether BSS Transition Management is enabled for the connection */
    uint32_t mbo_enabled:1;       /**< Whether MBO is enabled for the connection */
    uint32_t transition_disable:1;      /**< Whether to enable transition disable feature */
    uint32_t reserved:28;         /**< Reserved for future feature set */
    wifi_sae_pwe_method_t sae_pwe_h2e;     /**< Whether SAE hash to element is enabled */
    uint8_t failure_retry_cnt;    /**< Number of connection retries station will do before moving to next AP. scan_method should be set as WIFI_ALL_CHANNEL_SCAN to use this config. Note: Enabling this may cause connection time to increase incase best AP doesn't behave properly. */
} wifi_sta_config_t;
```

And some how, just code A work. Code B isn't work, I have an error WIFI_REASON_NO_AP_FOUND.
Can someone help to explain this issue?

Comment: It's most probably because in "code B" you leave a lot of members uninitialized. Instead of `wifi_config_t wifi_config;` make it `wifi_config_t wifi_config = {0};` and see if that helps. You can also skip the two `memset`s in "code B".

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here, so... When facing a problem like this just launch your debugger and look at the memory. What's actually stored and what's the difference. With some luck it would take you less time than it took to write this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "code A", the whole `wifi_sta_config_t` will be initialized. It's as-if you did

```c
memset(&wifi_config, 0, sizeof wifi_config);
```

before initializing the two members, `ssid` and `password`.

In "code B", that initialization is absent so, all the rest of the members in the `wifi_sta_config_t` are left uninitialized and reading from those will result in undefined behavior.

Either do

```c
memset(&wifi_config, 0, sizeof wifi_config);
```

before doing the two `memcpy`s, or initialize the whole instance directly when you create it and skip the `memset`s:

```c
static uint8_t wifi_ssid[sizeof (wifi_sta_config_t){}.ssid] = "my_ssid";
static uint8_t wifi_pwd[sizeof (wifi_sta_config_t){}.password] = "my_ssid_password";

// ...

void func() {
    wifi_config_t wifi_config = {0};                            // zero-initialize

    memcpy(wifi_config.sta.ssid, wifi_ssid, sizeof wifi_ssid);
    memcpy(wifi_config.sta.password, wifi_pwd, sizeof wifi_pwd);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot about to memset 0 for struct wifi_config_t